# MySQL can't start

Tags: mysql, centos, server

I have this error when MySQL wants to start:

> Starting MySQL..The server quit without updating PID file

And its MySQL error log:

> ```
> 151126 14:34:09 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.44) starting as process 12976 ...
> 151126 14:34:09 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
> /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
> 151126 14:34:09 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
> 151126 14:34:09 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
> 151126 14:34:09 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
> 151126 14:34:09 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
> 151126 14:34:09 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
> 151126 14:34:09 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
> 151126 14:34:09 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
> 151126 14:34:09 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
> InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
> InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
> 151126 14:34:09 InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
> InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
> InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
> InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
> InnoDB: buffer...
> 151126 14:34:09 InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
> 151126 14:34:10 InnoDB: 5.5.44 started; log sequence number 1595675
> 151126 14:34:10 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
> 151126 14:34:10 [Note] - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
> 151126 14:34:10 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
> 151126 14:34:10 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
> 151126 14:34:10 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/vps.hostdl.com.pid ended
> ```

CentOS 6 and MySQL 5.5. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your error is telling you what to do

> 151126 14:34:09 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.

Comment: [root@vps ~]# mysql_upgrade
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

Comment: try `mysql_upgrade --verbose` or `mysql_upgrade --port=3306 --user=root --password=YOURPASSWORD`. If neither works my last resort advise is: `mysql_upgrade -S /usr/local/mysql/mysql.sock` (replace filepath with your own filepath)

Comment: another thing you might try is this `mysql_upgrade -uadmin -p` apparently the root user for mysql is not always root, but admin.